# How can I create positions with an equal distance on a circle?

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, trigonometry

I am working on a script that should represent a circular grid. As the distance of the layers from the center increases, the number of objects in each layer increases proportionally, so the distance between each *tile* should stay constant. I tried to calculate an approximation of each *tile* on the fly by rounding the mouse world position, but this inherently caused problems like twitching around the beginning angle and moving the objects before the mouse even gets there.

Is this a totally bad approach or am I missing something?

Here is the code:

**customGrid.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class customGrid : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Camera mainCamera;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask layerMask; // this is a simple LayerMask attached to a simple Plane object

    public GameObject structure;

    Vector3 truePos;
    public int maxLayers = 1;
    public int minLayers = 0;
    public float objectSize = 1.5f;

    public float radius = 0f;
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        Ray ray = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit raycastHit, float.MaxValue, layerMask))
        {
            float angleRadian = Mathf.Atan2(raycastHit.point.x, raycastHit.point.z);
            float cursorDistanceFromOrigin = Vector3.Distance(Vector3.zero, new Vector3(raycastHit.point.x, 0, raycastHit.point.z));
            var circumference = 2 * Mathf.PI * radius;
            var quantization = 360 / (circumference / objectSize);

            float objectDistanceFromOrigin = Mathf.Floor(cursorDistanceFromOrigin / objectSize) * objectSize;

            var maxDistance = objectSize * maxLayers;
            var minDistance = objectSize * minLayers;

            objectDistanceFromOrigin = Mathf.Clamp(objectDistanceFromOrigin, minDistance, maxDistance);

            radius = objectDistanceFromOrigin;
            if (radius < 1) return;

            var degree = angleRadian * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            degree = Mathf.Round(degree / quantization) * quantization;
            angleRadian = degree * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
            truePos.x = Mathf.Sin(angleRadian) * radius;
            truePos.y = 0;
            truePos.z = Mathf.Cos(angleRadian) * radius;

            RepositionObject();
        }
    }

    private void RepositionObject()
    {
        structure.transform.position = truePos;
        var dir = truePos - Vector3.zero;
        dir = Vector3.Normalize(dir);
        structure.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir);
    }
}
```

[image: Flickering and buggy placement]

I am expecting a grid like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you draw roughly what you would expect the grid lines to look like?

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson sure! I added an image to the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the distances between the tiles to stay constant, then you need to pick from set of known tilings.

The simplest to work with is a hex tiling.  Unless you have good reason to do otherwise, I'd suggest that.

But [tessellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation) includes others, such as the [Voderberg
tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voderberg_tiling) which spirals in the way you want (at the cost of being very non-rectangular).

If you're willing to relax the distance rule, you can easily create a lot of tilings where the shape varies.  If you make the width 1.0471975512 times the height, and make your "tiles" into rounded sections, you'll get very close to approximate squares, with 6 more in each layer than the previous.  You can decide how you want that.

Note that anything other than a regular tiling like the hex tiling will make doing any kind of physics hard.  Which, as your game develops, is going to become a problem for you.